An application of Jensen's inequality on Gaussian Power
I am reading Structured Random Matrices(Ramon van Handel). Let $g$ be a Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unit variance. In lemma 3.1 of the aforementioned paper, it is stated that $\mathbb{E}[g^{2p-2}] \leq \mathbb{E}[g^{2p}]^{1-1/p}$ which follows from Jensen inequality. I fail to understand this. Can anyone help?

Try applying Jensen's inequality with function $x\mapsto x^{1-\frac1p}$.
